# paste one xib onto another xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xib

I want to paste blue view onto yellow one.

[screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x685ylnc8pxxoy4/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%202015%E5%B9%B47%E6%9C%889%E6%97%A5%20%E4%B8%8B%E5%8D%883.53.24.png?dl=0)

However, no matter how I change autolayouts of the blue one, there are conflicts.

Press button in the middle, and then the view will show.

[Xcode project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kc4oxxdsmldle5u/AACIpDEmI2XIMLJIqW5uCynba?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your file maned UIViewController+testAlert.m

```
containerFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.width;
```

just after

```
containerFrame.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
```

so your code of showAlertViewB function will be like

```
if (show) {
    NSArray* nibViews = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlertViewB" owner:self options:nil];
    alertViewB = (AlertViewB*)[nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
//        [alertViewB removeConstraint:alertViewB.containerHeightConstraint];
//        NSLayoutConstraint *newContainerHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:alertViewB attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1.0 constant:view.frame.size.height];
//        [alertViewB addConstraint:newContainerHeightConstraint];
    CGRect containerFrame = alertViewB.container.frame;
    containerFrame.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
    containerFrame.size.width = view.frame.size.width;
    [alertViewB.container setFrame:containerFrame];

    [alertViewB setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
    alertViewB.delegate =self;
    [alertViewB showWithView:view];
} else {
    [alertViewB removeFromSuperview];
    alertViewB = nil;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why this works?
Even if I comment out ViewController.m line 46~49, and UIViewController+testAlert.m line 41.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how setting frame within code interact with autolayout.

Comment: if you set frame for two view and use this setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints then it will automatically add necessary constraints in runtime accordingly. You did not changed the width of the view thats why it was not taking full width.